# Background performFetchWithCompletionHandler using Blocks causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, background-process

I have an app that successfully fetches and displays RSS Feeds that I'd like to add background fetch.  I receive:  Thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, Address=0x10) where indicated below.

In app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //setup background fetch
[application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval: UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];

return YES;
```

}

```
        //background fetch new RSS Feeds
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"performFetchWithCompletionHandler");
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    MasterViewController *navigationController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MasterView"];
    MasterViewController *viewController = navigationController;

    [viewController fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler:^(UIBackgroundFetchResult result) {
        completionHandler(result);
    }];
}
```

In my main ViewController:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^completionHandler)(BOOL);
- (void) fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler: (void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler;
- (void) startParsingWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler;

-(void)fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{

self.completionHandler = UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData; //completionHandler;
[self startParsingWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){

    if (success) {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
        NSLog(@"completionHandler");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"error");
    }
}];
```

}

```
    - (void) storyIsDone//called when parser completed one rss feed
{
    numberOfCompletedStories ++;
    if (numberOfCompletedStories == self.rssFeedAddresses.count)
    {
            //if all the feeds are done cancel time-out timer
        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget: self selector: @selector(stopParsing) object: nil];
        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        storysAreLoading = NO;
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reloadRSSfeeds) name: @"ReloadFeeds" object: nil];
        canRefresh = YES;
        NSLog(@"call back");
        self.completionHandler (YES);//crash here:  Thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, Address=0x10)
    }//else not yet complete
}
```

The output I receive is:

performFetchWithCompletionHandler

call back

Comment: self.completionHandler = UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData; fixed crash, but solved the crash, but now receive: Warning: Application delegate received call to -application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.   I Have discovered that self.completionHandler == nil when it gets to the storyIsDone method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
self.completionHandler = UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData;
```

does not match types.  `completionHandler` is of type `(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))` while `UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData` is of type `NSUInteger`.

```
typedef enum : NSUInteger {
   UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData,
   UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData,
   UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed 
} UIBackgroundFetchResult;
```

So when you call `self.completionHandler (YES)`, `self.completionHandler` is an `NSUInteger`, so `NSUInteger(YES)` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thank you.  That solved the crash, but now receive:   Warning: Application delegate received call to -application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Create a variable var completionHandler:((UIBackgroundFetchResult)->Void)!
when you receive a push notification set

```
self.completionHandler = completionHandler.
```

Then do your background stuff, typically download new data from a server.
When this is done, call the completionHandler like this:

```
if let handler = self.completionHandler{
    UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData
}
self.completionHandler = nil
```

Then you should get rid of that warning.